# Github private packages are not installing in docker build

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

I have an npm package hosted on github. It's working fine while working on the local machine. But it's not installing while the docker build process.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine as base
EXPOSE 8080
ARG LIB_GITHUB_TOKEN
ENV NODE_ENV=production \
LIB_GITHUB_TOKEN="${LIB_GITHUB_TOKEN}"
WORKDIR /home/node/app
RUN chown -R node:node /home/node/app
COPY --chown=node:node package.json package-lock*.json tsconfig.json .npmrc ./
RUN npm install --only=development
RUN ls -a **every pkgs installed except gihub pvt pkg** 
RUN cd node_modules/ && ls
RUN npm run build
```

.npmrc file

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@github_user:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${LIB_GITHUB_TOKEN}
```

Every packages are installed except my GitHub private package.

Same working properly with docker-compose.

If I add `npm ci --only=production` in dockerfile. it gives -

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="GitHub Package Registry"
```

Comment: Is ````"${LIB_GITHUB_TOKEN}"```` supposed to be in quotations?

Comment: @Matriarx Same problem with or without quotes.

Comment: How are you passing the build arg in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried using environment variables with `.npmrc` and I ran into the same 401 error you're experiencing. Instead of copying `.npmrc` into the image I added it to `.dockerignore`

And then do this in your Dockerfile

```
ARG github_token
ENV GITHUB_TOKEN=$github_token

RUN echo registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ >> ~/.npmrc
RUN echo @github_user:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/ >> ~/.npmrc
RUN echo //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=$GITHUB_TOKEN >> ~/.npmrc
```

And to build:

```
docker build . --build-arg github_token=${GITHUB_TOKEN}
```

Comment: This is not a recommended way to build docker image with secrets, as the github token will leak into the image data. Please use instead `--mount=type=secret,id=github_token` see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#secret